# Facebook graph API v12 users photos and likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, http-get, facebook-sdk-4.0

Back years ago I used the Facebook Graph API to gather users friend photos and likes for those photos. However, that was back when the API was v2.11 or v4 or something like that. Now at version 12, my code no longer works. I've tried getting the same data I once did back using their Graph API but I have no success in doing so.

I have the JSON below to show what data I used to get and which I am now trying to get again. Note that no links within the JSON will work - this is only an example.

Basically Its gathering my friends photos by their ID in ascending order and anyone who has liked those photo.

The call I would normally make to get this data was:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[user id]/picture?type=large&width=720&height=720
```

Are you still able to get other friends photos as well or has that been stopped now? Do your friends have to join your Facebook app in order to gather photo data like this from them?

```
{
    "data": [{
            "created_time": "2017-12-08T18:57:53+0000",
            "likes": {
                "data": [{
                        "name": "Bill Gates",
                        "id": "9485030985688759"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Bob Barker",
                        "id": "1944578789965397"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Steve Jobs",
                        "id": "4423564564766486"
                    }, {
                        "name": "James Bond",
                        "id": "1027785445557557"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Bart Simpson",
                        "id": "10214564574448423"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Lisa Simpson",
                        "id": "16845876543328680"
                    }
                ],
                "paging": {
                    "cursors": {
                        "before": "MTAyMHISTeY5MjYyOTE2NzQZD",
                        "after": "MTUzODUYTREEewQ5OTA2MwZDZD"
                    }
                }
            },
            "images": [{
                    "height": 960,
                    "source": "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-9\/243633743_10101633995322638_8617605831554312755_n.jpg?oh=d4ca434j6nrn4332d723981a8b3e7137e4&oe=5B044D79",
                    "width": 720
                }, {
                    "height": 800,
                    "source": "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p600x600\/24909743_10345633995322638_8614363524112755_n.jpg?oh=60e21c107fe171898452tre338a4c918&oe=5B479FB6",
                    "width": 600
                }, {
                    "height": 640,
                    "source": "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p480x480\/24909743_1013473995322638_861760343422414112755_n.jpg?oh=5302f74db20c780436nGddn16461f70&oe=5Bttr48C",
                    "width": 480
                }
            ],
            "id": "10101633993437538"
        }, {
            "created_time": "2017-06-05T21:14:28+0000",
            "likes": {
                "data": [{
                        "name": "Amy Someone",
                        "id": "453437546783720"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Mike LG",
                        "id": "181855436553221"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Homer Simpson",
                        "id": "194335643226397"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Bart Simpson",
                        "id": "194332353226397"
                    }
                ],
                "paging": {
                    "cursors": {
                        "before": "MTAyMTMRFeht5zg3MzM3MjAZD",
                        "after": "MTUzODcfrhreOTQ5OTA2MwZDZD"
                    }
                }
            },
            "images": [{
                    "height": 1440,
                    "source": "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t31.0-8\/18839799_10101467545354528_4346343h5628628521_o.jpg?oh=31297frt35y6e892c0807dad0345b58eb&oe=5B157345",
                    "width": 800
                }, {
                    "height": 1296,
                    "source": "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t31.0-8\/p720x720\/18839799_10101417914904528_4346353536428628521_o.jpg?oh=809bb29a5b55e222411a014c8392eea2&oe=5B47D7B8",
                    "width": 720
                }
            ],
            "id": "10134664346528"
        }
    ]
}
```

As a test I sent my wife a request to be a tester and she approved it but I still can not even pull data from her account?

[image]

As you see it just has my friend count and nothing more.

I also made sure it accepted my wife as a tester and it looks like it has:

[image]

But that does have a debug message saying:
[image]

Comment: You can only get data from users that granted permission to the app

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I sent my wife a request to be a tester and she has accepted it but I still can not see her data at least.

Comment: I did another test and just asked for my friends. It comes back with 534 friends but nothing more. And again, my wife is a tester so shouldn’t her name come up on the friends list at least since she has okayed the app? @WizKid

Comment: @WizKid updated my op with images of what I was talking about.

Comment: You need to use her user accesstoken to get her photos. And you both need to grant user_friends permission to the app to show up in the friends list

Comment: @WizKid will this need to happen when my app goes out of developer mode? Will they manually have to select permissions when they accept my non-developer mode app or will it tell them what permissions my app needs and once they confirm to install it then that’s all they have to do and I would be able to pull said data from them then?

Comment: As it looks now, with my wife set as a tester, she has to add the permissions within the graph api in order for me to see her info. But like I said before I can’t seem to get her photos and likes for each of her photos even with the correct permissions applied to the token.